# Find and Replace in Python- based on unknown characters

Tags: python, xml, python-2.7

I've been stumped on finding a way to find and replace characters based on position.
Basically what I am looking to do it go into a document and replace

```
<gco:DateTime>2016-04-20T11:27:34.8677919-06:00</gco:DateTime>
```

With

```
<gco:DateTime>2016-04-20T11:27:34</gco:DateTime>
```

**Everything after the decimal character must be deleted**.  The issue is, this is for multiple time stamps in XML files, and each of these time stamps are totally different.  I've read a bit on regex and it seems like a possible method. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Edit Example of XML file format:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type='text/xsl' href='http://ngis/ngis/metadata/StyleSheet/xslt/nGIS_Metadata.xslt'?>
<gmd:MD_Metadata xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml/3.2" xmlns:gmx="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gmx" xmlns:gts="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gts" xmlns:gfc="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gfc" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:gss="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gss" xmlns:gsr="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gsr" xmlns:gco="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gco" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:gmi="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gmi" xmlns:gmd="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gmd">
    <gmd:fileIdentifier>
        <gco:CharacterString>BF244A7CB62491BC74B001BE5DEAA213AAFB9DBA</gco:CharacterString>
    </gmd:fileIdentifier>
    <gmd:language>
        <gco:CharacterString>English</gco:CharacterString>
                <gmd:date>
                <gco:DateTime>2016-04-20T11:27:34.8677919-06:00</gco:DateTime>
                </gmd:date>
```

@Parfait

Comment: Regexes will solve this and other similar problems and you should keep reading about them. In this specific case parsing and formatting dates is also a good approach.

Comment: I would further caution you against trying to process XML much without actually parsing it into a proper tree using a library such as `lxml` or `ElementTree`, though you might get away with it if all your transormations are as uncomplicated.

Comment: It cannot be emphasized enough (perhaps the highest voted answer on SO), [do not regex html/xml files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider [XSLT](https://www.w3.org/Style/XSL/) (the special-purpose declarative language designed to transform XML documents) which has a very convenient function (shared with its sibling, XPath) for your needs [`substring-before()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/substring-before) where you extract the data prior to the period demarcating the timestamp. Python's `lxml` module can run XSLT 1.0 scripts.

Below script parses XML and XSLT from file. Specifically, the XSLT runs the Identity Transform to copy document as is and then extracts the time from **all** `<gco:DateTime>`. Note that only the needed `gco` namespace is defined in the XSLT header:

**XSLT** Script *(save as externally as .xsl file to be referenced in Python)*

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0"
               xmlns:gco="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gco">
<xsl:output version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <!-- Identity Transform -->
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="gco:DateTime">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:copy-of select="substring-before(., '.')"/>                  
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

**Python** Script

```
import lxml.etree as ET

# LOAD XML AND XSL
dom = ET.parse('Input.xml')
xslt = ET.parse('XSLTScript.xsl')

# TRANSFORM XML 
transform = ET.XSLT(xslt)
newdom = transform(dom)

# CONVERT TO STRING
tree_out = ET.tostring(newdom, encoding='UTF-8', pretty_print=True, xml_declaration=True)

# OUTPUT TREE TO FILE
xmlfile = open('Output.xml')
xmlfile.write(tree_out)
xmlfile.close()
```

**Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type='text/xsl' href='http://ngis/ngis/metadata/StyleSheet/xslt/nGIS_Metadata.xslt'?><gmd:MD_Metadata xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml/3.2" xmlns:gmx="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gmx" xmlns:gts="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gts" xmlns:gfc="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gfc" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:gss="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gss" xmlns:gsr="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gsr" xmlns:gco="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gco" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:gmi="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gmi" xmlns:gmd="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gmd">
  <gmd:fileIdentifier>
    <gco:CharacterString>BF244A7CB62491BC74B001BE5DEAA213AAFB9DBA</gco:CharacterString>
  </gmd:fileIdentifier>
  <gmd:language>
    <gco:CharacterString>English</gco:CharacterString>
    <gmd:date>
      <gco:DateTime>2016-04-20T11:27:34</gco:DateTime>
    </gmd:date>
  </gmd:language>
</gmd:MD_Metadata>
```

Comment: Thanks Parfait, this is working great.  Really appreciate it!

Comment: My files all start with
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type='text/xsl' href='http://xxxxx.com'?>
<gmd:MD_Metadata ... 

Anyway to have this script start from the third line instead of the 1st?  I am getting errors 
lxml.etree.XMLSyntaxError: Start tag expected, '<' not found, line 1, column 1

but obviously if I delete the first two lines it runs fine.  Thanks.

Comment: Please post snippet of actual xml (all of its headers as you have a namespace, `gco`, that should be defined). And you should not need to start from third line.

Comment: Just posted a sample xml in my original question.  I'm hoping to iterate this script through all folders with XML files.  And most of the XMLs have the same general format.

Comment: lxml.etree.XMLSyntaxError: XML declaration allowed only at the start of the document, line 2, column 16  is the error I get when pasting the entire the XML

Comment: As mentioned, you can parse both XML and XSL from file. See edit walking you through the steps. Simply iterate other files from directory.

Comment: Excellent thanks.  I ran into an error:
IOError: File not open for writing

but modified your xmlfile output with r+ and it is now working

# OUTPUT TREE TO FILE
xmlfile = open('Z:\FILENAME.xml',"r+")

Comment: Great. Interesting error, must be a python 2.7 vs 3.4 difference. Please accept answer to confirm resolution.

Answer (score 0):

One way:

```
s = "<gco:DateTime>2016-04-20T11:27:34.8677919-06:00</gco:DateTime>"
split_on_dot = s.split('.')
split_on_angle = split_on_dot[1].split('<')
new_s = "".join([split_on_dot[0], "<", split_on_angle[1]])

>>> new_s
'<gco:DateTime>2016-04-20T11:27:34</gco:DateTime>'
>>>
```

This depends on the period being the only period in the input string.  I'm not so good at regexes.  I think they get overused, but i'm sure someone will show you how using regex.  Just remember that python has good string manipulations natively.

Comment: Thanks joel, I would need this to be able to parse through multiple unknown dates for each file.  There are about 6 date stamps with this format in each file.  And the format is consistent through each, with only one period being used.

Comment: Then, good, but heed @holdenweb comments about xml parsing.  My answer just takes care of things once you have the element you want to change.  Stephen Holden introduced me to python in a course he taught